# How can I create a rule for using const and changing it's value

Tags: eslint

I'm trying to create a rule for my team that prefers `const` over `let` for things that don't change. However if the value changes then it should prefer a `let` instead (so it's easy to see what vars change over time).

Here's an example of what I would like it to do:

```
const colors = {red: '#f00'};
colors.red = '#00f';   // >>> prefer let for variables that change
colors.green = '#0f0';
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out where to start. Is there a way to do this without creating a new plugin?

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule present inside `eslint` itself called `prefer-const`.
You use that rather than creating your own.

Link: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const

Comment: I looked at that but it doesn't warn about mutating a const (though I realize this is a valid thing to do). I think I might give up on this and just use that and manually check for un-needed object/array mutations

Comment: You can always make a proposal for rules in eslint repo.